# Strapi's v4 custom authorization strategy

Tags: firebase, authentication, strapi

I am trying to do authorisation in Strapi via Firebase Phone Auth. Stumbled across an [article on the official forum](https://forum.strapi.io/t/is-custom-jwt-validation-available-in-v4/14201/2) that has a suggested solution. In the index.js file we add a new strategy and define firebase.

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  /**
   * An asynchronous register function that runs before
   * your application is initialized.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to extend code.
   */
  register({ strapi }) {
    strapi.container.get('auth').register('firebase', {
      name: 'firebase',
      async authenticate(ctx) {
        const { authorization } = ctx.request.header;

        // Check JWT in header
        if (authorization) {
          const parts = authorization.split(/\s+/);
          if (parts[0].toLowerCase() === 'bearer' && parts.length === 2) {
            const token = parts[1];

            try {
              // Verify JWT in Firebase
              const decodedToken = await strapi.firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

              // Check phone number from token and phone number in body
              if (decodedToken.phone_number === ctx.request.body.phoneNumber) {
                // Get user or create if user not found
                let user = await strapi
                  .query('user', 'users-permissions')
                  .findOne({ phoneNumber: ctx.request.body.phoneNumber });

                if (!user) {
                  // Create user if not found
                  user = await strapi
                    .query('user', 'users-permissions')
                    .create({ phoneNumber: ctx.request.body.phoneNumber });
                }

                // Set user in context state
                ctx.state.user = user;

                // Return credentials
                return { authenticated: true, credentials: user };
              }
            } catch (error) {
              // Error decoding
              console.error('Error JWT token firebase check:', error);
            }
          }
        }

        // Return error if auth with Firebase JWT failed
        return { authenticated: false };
      },
      async verify(ctx, next) {
        const { credentials } = ctx.state.auth;
        if (!checkIfCanAccessAdminTools()) {
          throw new ForbiddenError();
        }
        return 
      }
    });
  },

  /**
   * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
   * your application gets started.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
   * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
   */
  bootstrap({ strapi }) {
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    const serviceAccount = require("../private/firebase/serviceAccountKey.json");
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });

    strapi.firebase = admin;
  },
};
```

When I try to send request to http://localhost:1337/api/auth/firebase/authenticate, I get error Method Not Allowed.

If I try to send to http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local, I get the following error:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 401,
        "name": "UnauthorizedError",
        "message": "Missing or invalid credentials",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

There is a valid Firebase JWT token in the authorization header. There is also a phoneNumber in the request body.

What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed or improved?

Comment: I’ve would start by putting console.log in to that function and check if it’s actually getting called. I suspect it’s not so, you likely need to find how to hit that function, the good start would be to try use some official custom auth provider and see how it’s implemented.

Comment: Suspect you are likely missing routes, or you need to provide some argument to local auth that would use fire base then…